# Electrical Voltage Conversion Confusion

Tags: voltage, transformer, output, input, volts

so my friend bought a drumset from America and had it shipped all the way here to Amman, Jordan. Of course im going to need a convertor for the voltage difference between the 2 countries. However I'm confused as the battery for the drumset has 2 different stickers with 2 different voltage requirements on it (See attached photos). One sticker says input 100-240V and the other says 100V. However im also confused since isnt the defualt electrical output in America already 120V? Higher than the requirement?

Furthermore i have a 220V to 110V convertor not 100V, would that 10V difference make any difference? Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to [this document](https://static.roland.com/assets/media/pdf/roland_ac_adaptor_information.pdf) the adapter takes any AC voltage between 100 and 240V and either 50 or 60Hz. So you can use it directly without converter.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer @Unimportant ! But it wouldnt hurt the device to use a 110V convertor just in case right?

Comment: @MunirAwwad It should work fine with the converter aswell.